# mySQL auto-increment + auto adjust id by dynamicly deleting table content via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I am currently trying to build a "ToDo-App" which lets me `INSERT` text into a database, which will then be displayed. There is a "feature" to delete content based on their `ID`.

If I input two tasks into my application, I get two table records with `ID` 1 and 2. When I delete record 1, the record with ID 2 still exists. Thus, the record with `ID` 2 is listed as the first item in the to-do list.

I have to enter "2" in the "delete input field" to delete the first item from the list! How can I get this to be in sync? Is the `ID` field appropriate for maintaining the logical / application level order of the tasks?

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ToDo-APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Lil-Helper.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webfonts/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/own.css">

</head>


<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("","root","","todo");
    $sql = "SELECT text FROM work";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


    if(isset($_POST["text"]))
    {
        $eingabe = $_POST["text"];
        $query = "INSERT INTO work(text) VALUES('$eingabe')";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "";
    }



    if(isset($_POST["del"]))
    {
        $del = $_POST["del"];
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM `work` WHERE `work`.`id` = $del";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "";
    }

?>
<body>
    <header class="lil-menu lil-flex lil-flex-center align-center">
        <a href="index.html" class="lil-brand">
            <h3>To-Do</h3>
        </a>
        <a class="lil-menu-item currentLink" href="index.html">ToDo</a>
        <a class="lil-menu-item" href="#archive">Archiv</a>
        <a class="lil-menu-item" href="#Sprachen">Sprachen</a>
    </header>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="lil-box">
            <h3 class="lil-font-rot lil-big-font lil-space lil-font-style" style="font-size: 4rem;">ToDo</h3>
              <div class="lil-box">
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <input  class="lil-input" name="text" type="text">
                <input type="submit" class="lil-button-green" value="Hinzufügen">

            </form>

                <ol id="liste" class="lil-list">
                    <?php
                    while($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                    {
                        echo "<li>" .$dsatz["text"] ."</li>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </ol>
            <form id="form" action="index.php" method="post">
                <input  class="lil-input" name="del" type="text">
                <input type="submit" class="lil-button-red lil-button-small" value="   Löschen   ">
            </form>
            </div>       
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var anzahl = $("#liste li").length; 
    if(anzahl < 1)
    {
        $("#form").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("form").show();
    }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The pictures:

**HTML Output**
[image: HTML Output]
**MySQL Dashboard**
[image: MySQL Dashboard]

Comment: Do You wanna type the list key instead id ?

Comment: Yes, because the list key adjusts itself. If I have 2 listings, and I delete the first, number 2 becomes number 1.. so if I could delete the listings by the list-key (ordered list) that would be perfect.

Comment: Why do you want a text input field? Usually we use checkboxes to mark items and have some action buttons like delete, edit aso. like in your MySQL Dashboard.

Comment: That would be also cool, but I couldn't imagine, how to code that..

Comment: It is advisable to use a primary key for database table record uniqueness, not application level view ordering. I would create another field in the table called `order`. Hence, deleting would be based on the `order` field, not the `id` field. Remember, if you ever have to move the tasks up and down, the `id` field will quickly reveal itself to be inadequate for this task! ;-) Sorting / filtering might also produce anomalous results (as the table grows and grows towards max table rows).

Comment: But how do I submit a new  "order" value on every click on the submit button? How do I check automaticly he last value in "order"?

Comment: Your question resolves to, what must I truly do to add a record. Upon doing an `INSERT`, the value of the `order` field should be the max value found in the `order` column, plus 1. Yes, this means you must manage the order field for all CRUD operations, and what to do depends on where the operation takes place. Adds always go to the end of the table. Fine. Deleting from the end of the list is easy. Adding and deleting from the top or middle of the order takes a little bit more thought, but it boils down to incrementing or decrementing the `order` values of other entries, based on position.

Comment: The key is to break down the tasks: INSERTS, UPDATE, DELETE. Now, for each of these tasks, ask 1) What happens if I start at the top? 2) What happens if I start in the middle? 2) What happens if I start at the end?  Effectively, the combination of SQL task and `order` number must be determined for each click. If you are using AJAX, your event handlers should be "mapped" so to speak to specific server-side / PHP methods (or functions). You do need to submit the order number. You have two choices. Maintain the order in JavaScript data structure, or pull it from the DOM.

Comment: Older techniques include using `<input type="hidden" value="1">` and such, but then you'd have to maintain the hidden fields, too. If you are not using JavaScript or AJAX, then you must redraw the form each time. This means you might have to use hidden fields and make them "sticky" so that upon each draw of the screen the correct order is presented (as represented in the table).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment, you can have multiple checkboxes forming an array parameter: `<input name="theName[1]">` with explicit key and `name="theName[]"` with implicit keys.

Further more, you should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. Imagine an attacker sends a request with a single quote `'` in the field, i.e. he terminates the SQL string delimiter, and adds arbitrary SQL code. Prepared statements use placeholders and the parameters are sent separately.

You should also handle errors. In the code below errors are output as HTML, however, you should define your own logger function rather than just `echo` into the stream. This can output HTML on development servers but log to disk on production servers.

This is a working example tested on PHP7.3 with MariaDB 10:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ToDo-APP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Lil-Helper.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webfonts/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/own.css">
  <style>
    #frm-tasks button
    {
      padding: 0 18px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
  try
  {
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'testuser', 'testpasswd', 'testdb');

    $action = $_POST['action'] ?? 'list';

    if(!empty($_POST["text"]))
    {
      $eingabe = $_POST["text"];
      try
      {
        $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO work(text) VALUES(?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST["text"]);
        $stmt->execute();
      }
      catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
      {
        $msg = $e->getMessage();
        echo "<div>Error processing statement: $msg;</div>";
      }
    }


    if('del' === $action && isset($_POST['rows']) && is_array($_POST['rows']))
    {
      try{
        $stmt = $con->prepare('DELETE FROM `work` WHERE `work`.`id` = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $row);

        foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row)
        {
          $stmt->execute();
          if($e = $stmt->error)
            echo "<div>DB Error: $e</div>";

        }
      }
      catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
      {
        $msg = $e->getMessage();
        echo "<div>Error processing statement: $msg;</div>";
      }
    }

?>
  <header class="lil-menu lil-flex lil-flex-center align-center">
    <a href="index.html" class="lil-brand">
      <h3>To-Do</h3>
    </a>
    <a class="lil-menu-item currentLink" href="index.html">ToDo</a>
    <a class="lil-menu-item" href="#archive">Archiv</a>
    <a class="lil-menu-item" href="#Sprachen">Sprachen</a>
  </header>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="lil-box">
      <h3 class="lil-font-rot lil-big-font lil-space lil-font-style" style="font-size: 4rem;">ToDo</h3>
      <div class="lil-box">
        <!--form action="index.php" method="post"-->
        <form id="frm-tasks" action="" method="post">
          <input  class="lil-input" name="text" type="text">
          <button type="submit" class="lil-button-green" name="action" value="add">Hinzufügen</button>
<?php
    try
    {
      $res = $con->query('SELECT id, text FROM work');
      if(0 < $res->num_rows)
      {
?>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th><th>ID</th> <th>Aufgabe</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
        while($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_object($res))
        {
?>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="rows[]" value="<?php echo $dsatz->id;?>"></td><td><?php echo $dsatz->id;?></td> <td><?php echo $dsatz->text;?></td>
              </tr>
<?php
        }
?>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <button type="submit" class="lil-button-red lil-button-small" name="action" value="del">Löschen</button>
<?php
      }
    }
    catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
    {
      $msg = $e->getMessage();
      echo "<div>Error processing statement: $e->msg;</div>";
    }
?>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- not needed atm  script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script-->

  <h2>POST</h2>
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
  }
  catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
  {
    $msg = $e->getMessage();
    echo "<div>Error connecting DB: $msg;</div>";
  }
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Alright, I'll take some time tomorrow to study your answer. The code with the error reports etc works great, but it works as same as mine, like it's also with the number problem.. but I'll  check what you exactly wrote, like tomorrow ^^

Comment: @Tom The numbers are the database ID but ordinary enumeration.

Comment: Nevertheless I even simplified that again since checkbox value was not uses for other purpose. It transports the id now rather than the array key.

Comment: For some reason it keeps telling me: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\todo\index.php on line 133"

I just added a closing </body> and </html>, and even without it, it doesn't work for some reason..

Comment: I fixed it by replacing the old <li></li> line with:
echo "<li style='display: inline;'>" .$dsatz["text"] ."</li><input type='radio' name='eintrag' value='" .$dsatz['id'] . "' style='float: right;'><br>"; 

Which puts a radiobutton near every listing. Now the Code checks, if a radiobutton is selected, put's the value (which is the id from the database) in a variable, which will be used to delete the record.

Comment: SO code format has beed disrupted by too little indentation in one line. Fixed that.

Comment: Yes, your code above also works. But I guess it's more user friendly if there's only one button at all. So when there are listings, it looks like that: https://gyazo.com/1c13edc089cb9a098bba959845cbff05

Answer (score -1):

The key of the list is the 'th' in the database so just fixing limits

Replace

```
if(isset($_POST["del"]))
    {
        $del = $_POST["del"];
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM `work` WHERE `work`.`id` = $del";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
```

With

```
if(isset($_POST["del"]))
    {
        $del = $_POST["del"];
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM `work` LIMIT 1 OFFSET ".array_search($del, mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));
        mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
```

Comment: I can't delete listings then. It appears for a millisecond or so, and then comes back right, where it was before.

Comment: This strategy does not bode well for adding a full complement of operations: adding, deleting, and moving. For a problem like this, there should definitely be a `WHERE` clause in a DELETE statement. In this case the conditional should point to a specific value in an `order` field. LIMIT 1 is fine after that. Your delete process is far too involved and inefficient.